# for loop using to_csv, is only looping once

Tags: python, export-to-csv

I have a script that uses a for loop to read and clean a csv file then the result will save it as a new csv file. The loop for reading and cleaning works fine for all my csv files, until it reaches the 'to_csv' function. It appears it only saves the first csv file but not all.

Here is my script

```html
files_directory = 'C:/Users/Downloads/data/raw_data'
raw_files = os.listdir(files_directory)
csv_files = [] 

def clean_df(csv_files):
    for files in raw_files:
      csv_files.append('{}/{}'.format(files_directory,files))

    for file in csv_files:
        df = pd.read_csv(file, parse_dates=True)

        ### Clean leap years and create just one colum with all data
        df = df.dropna(axis=0) #remove row with feb 29
        df1 = df.drop(df.columns[[0,1]], axis = 1) #remove month and day column
        data = pd.Series(df1.values.ravel('A'))
        
        ##Create years dataframe
        year=list(df1)
        a = [np.repeat(yr, 366) for yr in year]
        df3= pd.DataFrame(a)
        years = pd.Series(df3.values.ravel('C'))
        
        ### Create dataframe with D/Y Dataframe
        months = df.drop(df.columns[[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]], axis = 1)
        months = pd.concat([months]*13, ignore_index=True)
        
        ### Create dataframe with M/D/Y 
        timestep = pd.concat(([months, years]), axis=1, join='inner')
        timestep.columns = ['Month', 'Day', 'Year']
        nat = pd.concat([timestep, data], axis=1, join='inner')
        print(nat)
        
        ## Save it to csv
        only_file_name = csv_files[0].split("/")[-1][0:-4]
        nat.to_csv('{}/{}_new.csv'.format(files_directory, only_file_name), index=False, mode='w') #if mode is a then it will copy paste below
        
        return csv_files

clean_df(csv_files)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers

Comment: Assuming the indentation in this post matches what's in your actual code, I am suspicious of the `return csv_files` line. You almost never want to have an unconditional return inside a loop, because that causes the loop to terminate completely in the first iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
only_file_name = csv_files[0].split("/")[-1][0:-4]
```

You are always using a modified version of the first file name at each iteration of the loop.  So every time, you write over the same file.  It seems like instead you should use:

```
only_file_name = file.split("/")[-1][0:-4]
```

(I would also avoid using `file` as a variable name, since that is a builtin in Python 2.)

Comment: While `file` _is_ a built-in type in Python 2.7, it's rare that you would need to access it directly when `open` is usually the easier approach. And it's not a built-in at all in 3.X. So IMO overshadowing that particular name is not much of a transgression :-) That said, I would much prefer `filename` over `file` in this particular context.

Comment: Thank you so much 0x5453 and Kevin, I've added your recommendations and it works!